# How to check button clicked in new UI button of unity 5.0

Tags: button, unity-game-engine

I added the new UI buttons of unity 5.0 in place of the old GUI texture buttons
in these buttons how to i check when the button has been pressed and released

and how to make the Onclick event keep repeating itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an Event Trigger component to your button . From there you can add a listener for `OnPointerUp` for when mouse is released and `OnPointerDown` for when mouse is pressed